# Batch code: how to pass a parameter choosing from an input list?

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I'm really new in this forum so I hope to respect all your rules, if not please forgive me!

I've just started studying something about batch files and I'm trying to execute a simple program from batch passing a parameter (the last aim is to submit a SAS program passing a date parameter).

Is it possible to activate a sort of list where I can choose some between pre-defined parameters?

**--> This is the real aim of my work**

I'm trying to "play" with this code:

```
    @echo off

    title Setting up execution period

    echo Insert your date in the format GGMMMAAAA (es: '31DEC2003'D).

    SET /p data_par=Insert the date to filter datas:

    SET first_byte=%data_par:~1,1%

    if "%first_byte%"=="" (

           GOTO tag1 

    ) else (

           GOTO tag2
)

:tag1
   msg * Missing value

:tag2
   msg * Well done!

pause
```

I've tried in a lot of ways but it looks like the IF statement is not executed, I don't know where am I wrong.

Another question: why the prompt closes after i press "Enter" (afte the set/p command is executed)?

--> this has been resolved putting the "pause" command at the end of the script.

Thank you all for the attention,

Best regards!

Squotty

Comment: just a hint: `%var:~1,1%` is not the first, but the second byte (it starts counting with zero).

Comment: if you just press enter, %data_par% will be empty, so `%data_par:~1,1%` makes no sense. Why do you extract a single char to check? Just use `if "%data_par%"=="" (`

Answer (score 1):

Put a `pause` at the end of your code to see the errormessages.

correct syntax for `if` when using `else` is:

```
if "a"=="b" (dosomething) else (dosemethingelse)
```

You can write it in several lines, but there are rules, where to set the paratheses:

```
if "a"=="b" (
  echo this is code for something
  rem more lines possible
) else (
  echo this is code for something else
  rem more lines possible
)
```

The first `(` has to be on the same line than `if`.

`) else (` have to be on one line.

If you press just enter with `set /p`, the variable remains unchanged (propably empty), so your code will go on with the code and hits the line `else`. Here it will tell you "else is not recognized as a command..."

at your `tagx` you should tell batch, where to stop execution. Use `goto :eof` to stop execution or `goto somewhere` to continue somewhere else. If you don't, it will just continue with the next lines.

Example:

```
:tag1
   msg * Missing value
   goto :eof
:tag2
   msg * Well done!
   goto :continue
pause
:continue
REM go on with the program...
```

(note: the `pause` will never be reached. I let it there to show you, how things work)

**EDIT** instead of just checking for some input you can check for the correct format:

```
echo %data_par%|findstr /r "[0-3][0-9][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][1-2]0[0-9][0-9]">nul && (
  echo correct format 
  goto continue
)  || (
  echo wrong format
  goto startover
)
```

It's not bullet proof (eg. `38ABC2019` would be considered "correct"), but at least it checks for the correct format (e.g. `15.12.2019` or `12/15/2014` would be "not correct")

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, now the situation is better but still different from what I want.
I tried making changes but now it always goes on the "Well done" condition, even if I don't enter any parameter.
By the way, is there a way to make the user choicing from a list of given dates?
Thanks again.
Squotty

Comment: Can you edit your question to show your actual code and it's problem(s)? I assume it's because of a missing `exit` or `goto :eof` at the end of your "`tag1`" code. After `msg * Missing value` the batch file just continues with the next lines, ignoring the next label and execute `msg * Well done!`

Comment: Hello Stephan, Thank a lot again for your answer and for the suggestion about the correct format.
Now the if cycle is correct and i'm trying to go but i have some problems with the check of the format. Unfortunately for the moment I don't have any time, I will try to go on in the next days and I will update my comment if I need help!
Thanks again
Squotty

Comment: Why do we use the "echo" statement to check the format if it is normally used just to display messages on the screen?

Comment: `echo` is used to write something. The following pipe symbol `|` takes that someting (instead of writing it to the screen) and passes it to the following command `findstr`, which searches for a pattern and if it found a matching pattern (`&&`) it does somecommand, if the pattern is not matched (`||`) it does anothercommand. Btw: I just noticed, my code did output the variable to the screen again. I corrected this.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, you are a good master!
I will try to manage with the check of format and I'll let you know about that, best regards!

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET "item1=date1"
SET "item2=date2"
SET "item3=date3"
SET "item4=date4"

FOR /l %%a IN (1,1,4) DO CALL ECHO(%%a. %%item%%a%%
ECHO(U. User-specified
choice /c 1234u
CALL SET selection=%%item%errorlevel%%%
IF NOT DEFINED selection (
 SET /p selection="Your date-selection ? "
)
IF NOT DEFINED selection ECHO No selection made&GOTO :EOF 
ECHO selection is %selection%

GOTO :EOF
```

This code may be of assistance.

It's normal to develop batch code using a batch window. Simply set up a shortcut to `command prompt` (Start>Programs>Accessories) which would allow you to run the script over and over and retain the results on-screen without using 'pause'. Editing can be accomplished by using `notepad batchfilename.bat` from the prompt (if you are using notepad for an editor - if using something better, then substitute that program's name). You can exit from the batch window by executing an `exit` command.

You can also get help on batch commands by using `commandname /?` - it's often cryptic and there are plenty of quirks. Extensive help available here on SO.

Comment: Hey Magoo, thanks a lot for your help!
It's useful to execute my bat from the prompt instead of the "double click" on the file, but i noticed a different behaviour of the same program:
- if I execute with a double click it works fine
- if I run it from the prompt it doesn't aplly the correct logic for the IF condition. I mean, if I press enter without entering any parameter the program tells me "Well done".
Why that?!?!
I think your code is a little hard to understand for me, I am really at the beginning with bat files...I'll try to study it :)
Thanks again!

Comment: If you start it from cmd line, the variable may be still set from the previous run. If you hit just `enter`, the variable remains untouched. I don't know, how your latest code looks like. If you still try to extract a single char from your input, this would also make trouble, when the input is "empty".